# Definition of 'application environment' , 'Framework' , 'API'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, api, frameworks, macos-carbon

Is it true :

Cocoa is an `application environment` that consist of several `Frameworks`
and each framework consist of several `API`

`Application Environment` -> `Framework` -> `API`

Is Carbon the other application environment in OSX?

Comment: I guess that is correct. I also guess there are different ways to slice up these three terms. Why are you asking for this? Depending on  the circumstances an understanding of the concepts can be more important than the exact terminology (which varies from vendor to vendor).

Comment: @Thilo: please look at below answer if that is correct means that my definition is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All things that allow an application to talk to a computer are an "API." That's a very broad term. It may refer to something as small as malloc, or as large as Cocoa. All of these are "APIs" in the broadest sense of the term.

On Mac and iOS, "framework" can have a specific meaning, which is a dynamically loadable bundle in a specific format. It can also have a broad meaning of "a collection of libraries that work together." There is a Cocoa.framework, but there is also the broader architecture of "Cocoa" which is a way of attacking problems together with a set of tools for attacking problems in that way.

An "Application Environment" is any environment that applications can run in. So Mac OS X could be considered an App Environment, or you might consider Darwin to be an App Environment, or Cocoa, or Carbon. It depends on what you're comparing it to.

The point in all of this are that these are not industry-wide well-defined terms. They're used to mean a lot of overlapping things, and they are sometimes used slightly different ways even within the Apple docs.

If you're looking for a good reference on general terms and how Apple uses them, you want to read [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AccessorMethod.html).

Answer (score 1):

What the wiki says :

> **Carbon** is one of Apple Inc.'s procedural application programming
>   interfaces (APIs) for the Macintosh operating system. It provides C
>   programming language access to Macintosh system services. Carbon
>   provides a good degree of backward compatibility for programs to run
>   on the now-obsolete Mac OS 8 and 9, however these systems are no
>   longer actively supported since Apple released the final OS 9 update
>   in December 2001.

In a few words, BOTH Cocoa and Carbon are considered APIs.

---

***Sidenote :** Why do you care so much about terminology? I definitely wouldn't. IMHO, it's the inner logic and concepts that matter; and not, necessarily, how we call it. Just my 2 cents....*

Comment: I also see it,but if cocoa and carbon are API,means that the definition that i write in question is wrong because in that definition 'API' is subsection of 'Framework' and cocoa and carbon consist of several frameworks

Comment: You can define Framework as a collection of APIs if you want. No one will disagree with that. If that is "right" or "wrong" depends on why the exact terms are important.